# How to use REDUCE with API REST Neo4j?

Tags: rest, neo4j

I want to use a Function REDUCE through a query with API REST of Neo4J. I tried :

```
:POST /db/data/cypher {
  "query" :
    "MATCH p=(n:SOL { PRB : {PRB}})-[r]-(m:SOL { PRB : {PRB2} }) 
    RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p)" AS Experiences,
    reduce(CONS=(1), r in relationships(p)|CONS*r.points) AS Impact,
  "params" : {
    "PRB" : "Beginning",
    "PRB2" : "End"
  }
}
```

As I used successfuly in Neo4j Browser, with adaptation for "params" according to API REST. But it doesn't work, I shall obtain : "Payload does not seem to be valid (JSON) data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `"` character in the 4th row, that's why the JSON does not get parsed. This should work:

```
:POST /db/data/cypher {
    "query": "MATCH p=(n:SOL { PRB : {PRB}})-[r]-(m:SOL { PRB : {PRB2} }) RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p) AS Experiences, reduce(CONS = (1), r in relationships(p) | CONS * r.points) AS Impact ",
    "params": {
        "PRB": "Beginning",
        "PRB2": "End"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, but it does still not work. Same response.

Comment: I put the string to a single line and added a missing comma. Please check.

Comment: Well that's the query's issue. Does the query work somewhere else, e.g. in the Neo4j browser UI?

Comment: No, it does'nt word. The response is : "Could not fetch URL: "Failed to fetch". This could be due to the remote server policy. See your web browsers error console for more information."

Comment: I find the mistake : there was a "r" in -[...]- instead of -[*]-, as it should be. Now, it works ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a typo error. The " character should be placed in the end of the Cypher query instead of after `nodes(p)`. Try:

```
:POST /db/data/cypher {
  "query" :
    "MATCH p=(n:SOL { PRB : {PRB}})-[r]-(m:SOL { PRB : {PRB2} }) 
    RETURN DISTINCT nodes(p) AS Experiences,
    reduce(CONS=(1), r in relationships(p)|CONS*r.points) AS Impact",
  "params" : {
    "PRB" : "Beginning",
    "PRB2" : "End"
  }
}
```